# Use SharePoint as a UI to a SQL table

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Can I use a SharePoint list as a user interface to a table in my SQL db?
Mean - the user can read form the db and write there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure you can. [This is a pretty good guide.](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/add-a-database-as-a-data-source-HA010355745.aspx)

You can specify which columns to show, specify custom queries, order, filter, join...

Furthermore, you could also use the SSRS integration package to display it in a more BI-friendly manner... but if all you want is to expose SQL through a SharePoint list, the link above will do.

Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks! I make a data source, but how can I connect a list to this data source?

Comment: You do all that through SharePoint Designer. It's pretty self-intuitive.